# BizTalk undeploy error MSB3073: The command ... exited with code 1

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, biztalk, undeploy

I'm having an issue with the undeploy action of a BizTalk solution (TM.UPS). I have built a msi and have succesfully deployed it. However with undeploying it, I get the error message below. The weird thing is that when I build the installer MSI on a different developer machine but from the EXACT SAME sourcecode, I don't get an error while undeploying the solution. So it looks like some regional (?) setting on my developer pc. We are using the deployment framework.

I know the issue happens with solutions that are using orchestrations. MSI's built without an orchestration don't have issues, however solutions with orchestrations built on my pc do have this issue. If they are built on another pc, then they are good.

I know this is a long reach, but does someone have an idea what the issue can be? With undeploying or perhaps what the difference between my pc and the other pc can be?

This is the errorcode I get while undeploying the solution that was created on my developer pc:

```
Build started 9-2-2017 15:03:30.
Overriding target "CustomPostExportSettings" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "CustomPostExportSettings" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "CustomFinalDeploy" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "CustomFinalDeploy" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "CustomFinalUndeploy" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "CustomFinalUndeploy" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "DeployAppDefinition" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "DeployAppDefinition" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "UndeployAppDefinition" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "UndeployAppDefinition" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "VerifyBizTalkAppExists" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "VerifyBizTalkAppExists" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "CustomRedist" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.WiXSetup.targets" with target "CustomRedist" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj".
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" on node 1 (Undeploy target(s)).
Building with tools version "4.0".
Target "SetUndeployProperties" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "Undeploy" depends on it):
Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Message"
  UNDEPLOYING APPLICATION FROM BIZTALK...
Done executing task "Message".
Done building target "SetUndeployProperties" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "CustomPreExportSettings" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "ExportSettings" depends on it):
Done building target "CustomPreExportSettings" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "ExportSettings" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "InitSettingsFilePath" depends on it):
Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(EffectiveSettingsSpreadsheetPath)')) was evaluated as (!Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\EnvironmentSettings\SettingsFileGenerator.xml')).
Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Exec"
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools\EnvironmentSettingsExporter.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\EnvironmentSettings\SettingsFileGenerator.xml" "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\EnvironmentSettings"
  Environment Settings Spreadsheet to XML Exporter 1.6.1
  [http://EnvSettingsManager.codeplex.com]
  Copyright (C) 2007-11 Thomas F. Abraham.  All Rights Reserved.

  Importing from SettingsFileGenerator.xml...

  Output format is XmlPreprocess (multi-file).

  Exporting to Exported_LocalSettings.xml...
  Exporting to Exported_DevSettings.xml...
  Exporting to Exported_TestSettings.xml...
  Exporting to Exported_ProdSettings.xml...

  Finished.
Done executing task "Exec".
Done building target "ExportSettings" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "InitSettingsFilePath" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "SetPropertiesFromEnvironmentSettings" depends on it):
Task "SetRegistryValue" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(Configuration)' == 'Server' and '$(DeploymentMode)' == 'Deploy' and '$(SettingsFilePath)' != '') was evaluated as ('Server' == 'Server' and 'Undeploy' == 'Deploy' and '' != '').
Task "Message"
  Invalid settings file path.
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
Done building target "InitSettingsFilePath" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "SetPropertiesFromEnvironmentSettings" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "LoadPropsFromEnvSettingsThenExecute" depends on it):
Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '' and Exists('$(SettingsFilePath)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and Exists('')).
Task "SetPropFromEnvSetting" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '' and Exists('$(SettingsFilePath)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and Exists('')).
Task "SetPropFromEnvSetting" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '' and Exists('$(SettingsFilePath)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and Exists('')).
Task "SetPropFromEnvSetting" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '' and Exists('$(SettingsFilePath)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and Exists('')).
Task "SetPropFromEnvSetting" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '' and Exists('$(SettingsFilePath)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and Exists('')).
Task "SetPropFromEnvSetting" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '' and Exists('$(SettingsFilePath)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and Exists('')).
Task "SetPropFromEnvSetting" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '' and Exists('$(SettingsFilePath)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and Exists('')).
Task "GetPropsFromEnvSettingsDelimited" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SettingsFilePath)' != '' and Exists('$(SettingsFilePath)')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and Exists('')).
Done building target "SetPropertiesFromEnvironmentSettings" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "LoadPropsFromEnvSettingsThenExecute" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "Undeploy" depends on it):
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TargetsAfterLoadPropsFromEnvSettings)' == '') was evaluated as ('ServerUndeploy' == '').
Using "MSBuild" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "MSBuild"
  Global Properties:
    LoadedPropsFromEnvSettings=True
    SkipExportSettings=True
Overriding target "CustomPostExportSettings" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "CustomPostExportSettings" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "CustomFinalDeploy" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "CustomFinalDeploy" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "CustomFinalUndeploy" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "CustomFinalUndeploy" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "DeployAppDefinition" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "DeployAppDefinition" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "UndeployAppDefinition" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "UndeployAppDefinition" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "VerifyBizTalkAppExists" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" with target "VerifyBizTalkAppExists" from project "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets".
Overriding target "CustomRedist" in project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.WiXSetup.targets" with target "CustomRedist" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj".
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (1) is building "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (1:2) on node 1 (ServerUndeploy target(s)).
Building with tools version "4.0".
Target "SetServerUndeployProperties" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "ServerUndeploy" depends on it):
Done building target "SetServerUndeployProperties" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "SetPropertiesFromEnvironmentSettings" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(PropsFromEnvSettings)' != '' and '$(LoadedPropsFromEnvSettings)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('SsoAppUserGroup;SsoAppAdminGroup;ESBLookupConnectionString;ESBTrackingConnectionString;B2BUsername;B2BPassword' != '' and 'True' != 'true').
Target "LoadPropsFromEnvSettingsThenExecute" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "ServerUndeploy" depends on it):
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TargetsAfterLoadPropsFromEnvSettings)' == '') was evaluated as ('UndeployBizTalkMgmtDB_true' == '').
Task "MSBuild"
  Global Properties:
    LoadedPropsFromEnvSettings=True
    SkipExportSettings=True
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (1:2) is building "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (1:3) on node 1 (UndeployBizTalkMgmtDB_true target(s)).
Building with tools version "4.0".
Target "CustomPreInitialize" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "DevUndeploy" depends on it):
Done building target "CustomPreInitialize" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "PrintHeader" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "FrameworkInitialize" depends on it):
Task "Message"
  Using Deployment Framework Install Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\'.
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Using Deployment Framework Tools Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools'.
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Using .NET Framework Install Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'.
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Using BizTalk Install Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\'.
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(EsbDir)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
Task "Message"
  Detected IIS 8
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Using BizTalk Application Name 'TM.UPS'
Done executing task "Message".
Done building target "PrintHeader" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "ExportSettings" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SkipExportSettings)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('True' != 'true').
Target "CustomPostExportSettings" in file "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "FrameworkInitialize" depends on it):
Task "Message"
  PostExportSettingsFile started- Custom Task for Environment ACC
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Getting Settings from URL http://vmweb2venlo/DeploymentService/DeploymentSettingService.svc/wshttp  for Environment ACC
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(UseEnvSettingsDB)' == 'false') was evaluated as ('True' == 'false').
Using "GetEnvironmentSettingsTasks" task from assembly "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\\\Tasks\DevWeb.BizTalk.DeploymentFramework.Tasks.dll".
Task "GetEnvironmentSettingsTasks"
  User administrator called GetEnvironmentSettingsTasks for integration TM.UPS with version : 1.0.0 (ProductId:b05f5ba2-f413-4564-9414-1b72b09fd982) (ProductUpgradeCodeb76fa976-41ea-44e5-a0ca-bf1ce3c8667e) on date: 02/09/2017 15:03:30
  Setup Client   to http://vmweb2venlo/DeploymentService/DeploymentSettingService.svc/wshttp  
  Found 10 settings for this integration 
  Settings saved  to C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\EnvironmentSettings\ACC.xml settings for this integration 
Done executing task "GetEnvironmentSettingsTasks".
Done building target "CustomPostExportSettings" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "SetPropertiesFromEnvironmentSettings" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(PropsFromEnvSettings)' != '' and '$(LoadedPropsFromEnvSettings)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('SsoAppUserGroup;SsoAppAdminGroup;ESBLookupConnectionString;ESBTrackingConnectionString;B2BUsername;B2BPassword' != '' and 'True' != 'true').
Target "FrameworkInitialize" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "DevUndeploy" depends on it):
Done building target "FrameworkInitialize" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "CustomPostInitialize" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "DevUndeploy" depends on it):
Done building target "CustomPostInitialize" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "CustomUndeployTarget" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "DevUndeploy" depends on it):
Done building target "CustomUndeployTarget" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "InitializeAppName" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BizTalkAppName)' == '') was evaluated as ('TM.UPS' == '').
Target "VerifyBizTalkAppExists" in file "C:\Prog\Tools\BizTalkExtension\DeploymentFramework\Targets\1.0.0\Custom.BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "PrepareAppForUndeploy" depends on it):
Task "Message"
  VerifyBizTalkAppExists : Checking Application Existence
Done executing task "Message".
Using "GetBizTalkAppExists" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.Tasks.BizTalk.dll".
Task "GetBizTalkAppExists"
  Checking for existence of BizTalk application 'TM.UPS'...
  Found BizTalk application 'TM.UPS'.
Done executing task "GetBizTalkAppExists".
Done building target "VerifyBizTalkAppExists" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "PrepareAppForUndeploy" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "DevUndeploy" depends on it):
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(AppExists)' == 'false' and '$(DeploymentMode)' == 'Undeploy') was evaluated as ('True' == 'false' and '' == 'Undeploy').
Using "CallTarget" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "CallTarget"
Target "VerifyBizTalkAppExists" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target "StopApplicationViaBizTalk" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(UseLegacyApplicationControl)' == 'true' and '$(AppExists)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true' and 'True' == 'true').
Target "StopTheApplication" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "StopApplication" depends on it):
Task "Message"
  Stopping TM.UPS application at 02-09-17 03:03:31.
Done executing task "Message".
Using "ControlBizTalkReceiveLocations" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.Tasks.BizTalk.dll".
Task "ControlBizTalkReceiveLocations"
  Disabling receive location 'TM.UPS.CSVshipment_to_TM.Shared.Order'...
  Committing Receive Location actions...
  Committed Receive Location actions.
Done executing task "ControlBizTalkReceiveLocations".
Using "ControlBizTalkOrchestrations" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.Tasks.BizTalk.dll".
Task "ControlBizTalkOrchestrations"
  Unenlisting orchestration 'TM.UPS.Orchestrations.Orchestration_1'...
  Committing Orchestration actions...
  Committed Orchestration actions.
Done executing task "ControlBizTalkOrchestrations".
Using "ControlBizTalkSendPortGroups" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.Tasks.BizTalk.dll".
Task "ControlBizTalkSendPortGroups"
Done executing task "ControlBizTalkSendPortGroups".
Using "ControlBizTalkSendPorts" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.Tasks.BizTalk.dll".
Task "ControlBizTalkSendPorts"
  Unenlisting send port 'TM.UPS.SharedOrder_to_TM.Shared.Order'...
  Committing Send Port actions...
  Committed Send Port actions.
Done executing task "ControlBizTalkSendPorts".
Done building target "StopTheApplication" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "StopApplication" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "PrepareAppForUndeploy" depends on it):
Done building target "StopApplication" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Done executing task "CallTarget".
Task "CallTarget"
Target "TerminateServiceInstancesConditional" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(AutoTerminateInstances)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' == 'true').
Done executing task "CallTarget".
Using "CheckForServiceInstances" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.Tasks.BizTalk.dll".
Task "CheckForServiceInstances"
  Checking for existing service instances associated with application 'TM.UPS'...
  Done checking for existing service instances associated with application 'TM.UPS'.
Done executing task "CheckForServiceInstances".
Done building target "PrepareAppForUndeploy" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "StopBizTalk" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "ConditionalHostStop" depends on it):
Task "Exec" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SkipIISReset)' == 'false' and '@(IISAppPool)' == '') was evaluated as ('True' == 'false' and '' == '').
Task "RecycleAppPool" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SkipIISReset)' == 'false' and '@(IISAppPool)' != '') was evaluated as ('True' == 'false' and '' != '').
Task "CallTarget"
Target "StopAllBizTalkHosts" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "StopBizTalk" depends on it):
Task "Message"
  Host list (BizTalkHosts ItemGroup) not customized.
Done executing task "Message".
Using "ControlBizTalkHostInstance" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.Tasks.dll".
Task "ControlBizTalkHostInstance"
Done executing task "ControlBizTalkHostInstance".
Done building target "StopAllBizTalkHosts" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Done executing task "CallTarget".
Task "CallTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(BizTalkHosts)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
Done building target "StopBizTalk" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "ConditionalHostStop" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "DevUndeploy" depends on it):
Done building target "ConditionalHostStop" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "UndeployBam" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IncludeBAM)' == 'true' and ('$(SkipUndeploy)' == 'false' and '$(SkipBamUndeploy)' == 'false')) was evaluated as ('false' == 'true' and ('false' == 'false' and 'true' == 'false')).
Target "UndeployBtsNtSvcExeConfig" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "DevUndeploy" depends on it):
Task "UpdateBizTalkAppDomainConfig" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(UseIsolatedAppDomain)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true').
Done building target "UndeployBtsNtSvcExeConfig" in project "Deployment.btdfproj".
Target "UndeployEsbItineraries" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IncludeEsbItineraries)' == 'true' and '$(SkipUndeploy)' == 'false') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true' and 'false' == 'false').
Target "UndeployOrchestrations" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets" from project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (target "UndeploySchemas" depends on it):
Task "Exec"
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools\gacutil.exe" /u ""
  Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  Failure removing assembly from cache:   The parameter is incorrect.

C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(1305,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools\gacutil.exe" /u """ exited with code 1. [C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj]
Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.
Done building target "UndeployOrchestrations" in project "Deployment.btdfproj" -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (UndeployBizTalkMgmtDB_true target(s)) -- FAILED.

Done executing task "MSBuild" -- FAILED.
Done building target "LoadPropsFromEnvSettingsThenExecute" in project "Deployment.btdfproj" -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (ServerUndeploy target(s)) -- FAILED.

Done executing task "MSBuild" -- FAILED.
Done building target "LoadPropsFromEnvSettingsThenExecute" in project "Deployment.btdfproj" -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (Undeploy target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (Undeploy target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (ServerUndeploy target) (1:2) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (UndeployBizTalkMgmtDB_true target) (1:3) ->
(UndeployOrchestrations target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(1305,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools\gacutil.exe" /u """ exited with code 1. [C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.79
```

Answer (score 2):

The key error is

> Failure removing assembly from cache:   The parameter is incorrect.

Which occurs after

```
Task "Exec"  
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools\gacutil.exe" /u ""
```

There is no DLL name specified in the that command.
I would expect to see

```
Task "Exec"  
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\TM.UPS\1.0\Deployment\Framework\DeployTools\gacutil.exe" /u "projectname.dll"
```

So the place to check would be your deployment configuration to see if you have not defined one of your projects correctly.  Maybe your development environment has a stale copy of the file?   Force a get latest from your source repository